# I am trying to register users in mysql using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to register the admin and other users but my code doesn't work.Can anybody help me please?This is my code that I've used to create a database and a table.
This is the the link to the full code:http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=71664130076755188207

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {new  Aregistration();
createTable(); 
 }
//Table
public static void createTable() throws Exception{
    try{
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,first_name varchar(45),last_name varchar(45),email varchar(320),password varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(id))");
        create.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    finally {
        System.out.println("System Updated");};
}
//End of Table
//Database
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{

    try{
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/admin?useSSL=false";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "toor";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
}

https://postimg.org/image/ltgqcgqzp/
https://postimg.org/image/r65kqlew5/
```

Comment: There is no problem in the code you post.But can you post all of your code?Where is the class Aregistration.And how you register the admin and other users.What's the wrong prompt in the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ähm your code does exactly what it should... i dont get the Point obviusly you cant insert useres atm cause you never wrote a class for this ...

Like this one:

```
public static void insertNewUser(String id,String first_name,String last_name, String email,String password){
connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatment create = conn.prepareStatement("Insert into admin Values ?,?,?,?,?" );
PreparedStatment.setString(1,id);
PreparedStatment.setString(2,first_name);
PreparedStatment.setString(3,last_name);
PreparedStatment.setString(4,email);
PreparedStatment.setString(5,password);
PreparedStatment.exectueUpdate();
```

}